# How to create a new tenant other than the default one available in grafana-mimir (Open source version)?

Tags: grafana-mimir

I am evaluating the ***open source version of grafana-mimir*** and stuck in configuring multi tenancy . I have completed the following activities,

1. I have deployed garana-mimir in micro-service mode
2. Configured the mimir-gateway service to authenticate requests from grafana agent using TLS certificates
3. Also enabled grafana agent to be authenticated against mimir-gateway service using client certificate ( MTLS authentication )
4. Until this part everything looks fine and n ow I want to create new tenant in mimir and proceed with configuring authentication to authenticate the query using tenant-id.  I am really stuck here. Can you help me with the configuration to achieve my final goal ? Is this not possible with Open source version of grafana-mimir ?

Thanks in advance , Biju Joseph

Comment: I looking for the same answers , Di You find a solution?